# Error when using pandas trying to retrieve column data for categorical_subset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to use Sklearn tools alongside Pandas and np. I am trying to run my code (shown below the error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/AISyiff/testingAi.py", line 129, in <module>
    categorical_subset = pd.get_dummies(categorical_subset[categorical_subset.columns.drop("protocol")])
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\AISyiff\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5018, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['protocol'] not found in axis"
```

Please let me know where I've made the mistake and what I can do to fix this!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing as preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor

sns.set(style="white", context="talk")
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200
df = pd.read_csv("datasets_for_paper.csv", low_memory=False)

##firstPaint provides time info about page renderingso does ,rumSpeedIndex=avg page render
print(df.dtypes)
df["nodeId"] = df["nodeId"].astype(int)
df["numObj"] = df["numObj"].astype(int)
df["rumSpeedIndex"] = df['rumSpeedIndex'].astype(int)
df["pageLoadTime"] = df['pageLoadTime'].astype(int)
df["firstPaint"] = df['firstPaint'].astype(int)


# convert from name into pure string
def changeProtName(value):
    if value == 'H1s':
        return str('Hs')
    else:
        return str('Hl')


df['protocol'] = df['protocol'].map(lambda x: changeProtName(x))

# hot encode catagories as catagorical data
df['protocol'] = pd.Categorical(df["protocol"])
df['browser'] = pd.Categorical(df['browser'])
df['nodeType'] = pd.Categorical(df['nodeType'])
df['url'] = pd.Categorical(df['url'])


# list a bunch of details about categorical data
def summerize_data(df1):
    for column in df1.columns:
        print(column)
        if df.dtypes[column] == np.object:
            print(df1[column].value_counts())
        else:
            print(df1[column].describe())

        print('\n')


summerize_data(df)


def hotEncodingCats(df1):
    results = df1.copy()
    encoders = {}
    for column in results.columns:
        encoders[column] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        results[column] = encoders[column].fit_transform(results[column])
    return results, encoders


print(df.dtypes)

encoded_data, _ = hotEncodingCats(df)
sns.heatmap(encoded_data.corr(), square=True)


encoded_data.tail(5)

encoded_data, encoders = hotEncodingCats(df)
new_series = encoded_data["protocol"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(encoded_data[encoded_data.columns.drop("protocol")], new_series,
                                                    train_size=0.70)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train), columns=X_train.columns)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

cls = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

cls.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = cls.predict(X_test)

print(df.dtypes)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(df.dtypes)
print("cookieprint")

def mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(abs(y_true - y_pred))

print("cookie3")

def fit_and_evaluate(model):
    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Make predictions and evalute
    model_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    model_mae = mae(y_test, model_pred)

    # Return the performance metric
    return model_mae


print(fit_and_evaluate(cls))
print("cookie1")
random_forest = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=60)
coefs = pd.Series(cls.coef_[0], index=X_train.columns)
print(X_train.columns)
print("cookie2")
coefs = coefs.sort_values()
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
coefs.plot(kind="bar", alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
print(coefs.sort_values(ascending=False))

features = df.copy()
numeric_subset = df.select_dtypes('number')
categorical_subset = df.select_dtypes('object')

categorical_subset = pd.get_dummies(categorical_subset[categorical_subset.columns.drop("protocol")])
features = pd.concat([numeric_subset, categorical_subset], axis = 1)
print(features.head())
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `axis`, replace your line with `encoded_data[encoded_data.columns.drop("protocol", axis=1)]`

Comment: Yeah, but it was causing me problems further down the line so I had to change it to this unfortunately!

Comment: @YOLO is right. Make sure you define the axis or check if numeric_subset and categorical_subset on line 129 have the column 'protocol'

Comment: Which line should I add the axis to? When I add it to line 78 it tells: **TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'** 
My apologies if these are silly questions, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: One small tip unrelated to your problem: [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) takes a `dtype` argument to specify the data types of your columns if any of them are not the default (floating point).  E.g. you can pass `dtype={'nodeId': int, 'numObj': int, ...}` and so on and avoid all that `astype` stuff at the beginning.

Comment: I didn't actually know this, I'm v new to using dataframes so this kind of advice is extremely useful and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['protocol'] = pd.Categorical(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A'])
>>> df.select_dtypes('object')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
```

You can see that the last line, corresponding to

```
categorical_subset = df.select_dtypes('object')
```

is probably returning an empty `DataFrame` (when in doubt, it would have been good to check that `categorical_subset` actually contains what you expected it to contain.

This is because when you re-assigned `df['protocol']`, which originally contained strings, to a `pd.Categorical`, its dtype (as well as those of the other categorical columns) is no longer `object`, but rather `category`):

```
>>> df.dtypes
protocol    category
dtype: object
```

(this output looks a little confusing; it says the dtype of `protocol` is `category` but under that it says `dtype: object`: the return value of [`DataFrame.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html#pandas-dataframe-dtypes) is actually a `Series` with columns for the column name and the dtype, so the deceptive `dtype: object` at the bottom refers to the dtype of that series).

This is probably what you actually wanted:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes('category')
  protocol
0        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
4        A
```

In fact, it says [in the docs for `select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

> To select Pandas categorical dtypes, use `'category'`

The above is a good example of how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also in general how to debug small programs.  We first zeroed in on the problem area, the line

```
categorical_subset.columns.drop("protocol")
```

where it apparently thinks there shouldn't be a column called `'protocol'`.  Then we just work backwards to how `categorical_subset` was created (we called `df.select_dtypes('object')` on our original dataframe).  And then beyond that all we need is an example dataframe that has some `pd.Categorical` columns.